# Datadog: Slow queries from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, datadog

I have a MongoDB using the database profiler to collect the slowest queries. How can I send this information to Datadog and analyze it in my Datadog dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Once the datadog is properly installed on your server, you can use the custom metric feature to let datadog read your query result into a custom metric and then use that metric to create a dashboard.

You can find more on custom metric on datadog [here](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/208385813-Postgres-custom-metric-collection-explained)

They work with yaml file so be cautious with the formatting of the yaml file that will hold your custom metric.